# How to bypass wireguard vpn except some ports

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have some ubuntu hosts that are connected to a wireguard vpn. Each of them has a openssh server on port 22 and another service that serve in tcp on port 19999. Is there a way that all the traffic except the one from/to port 22 and 19999 bypass the vpn and goes trough their current connection? I think I have to set something with the `ip route` command but I don't know how it works at all and even if it is the one to use. I have already blocked the traffic in the wireguard server using iptables so the hosts at the moment just go on timeout when I like try to navigate on any website.

Let assume that a host has a vpn ip 10.13.1.1/32, local ip 192.168.1.2/24 and vpn gateway at 10.13.254.1. The local ip network could change.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

`ip route` is used to specify a route through a network or an interface , in your case you need to do a port forwarding using `iptables` and some nat rules

Comment: Ok, can you elaborate how?